Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah, upgrade to .NET8
I have multiple XML files in my C# application startup project, which are transformed at build time with SlowCheetah. Now I want to update the application to .NET8, but Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah is not supported in .NET8 anymore, so the package reference is removed when updating the startup project. Is there an alternative to SlowCheetah in .NET8 or what are the best practices for transfoming XML files in .NET8?
The XML Files are in the following scheme:

connections.config
connections.Debug.config
connections.Release.config

I tried upgrading to .NET8 and expected SlowCheetah to be supported. I upgraded SlowCheetah to verison 4.0.50 (newest version), but this didn't solve the problem

There are no .config files in .NET 8. .NET 8 is .NET Core 8, a completely different SDK and runtime. ASP.NET Core was rewritten from scratch and is completely different from the old ASP.NET "Classic". Instead of config files that require explicit transformations, ASP.NET Core configuration can load settings from a multitude of sources, including multiple files with different formats, without requiring transformations. "Newer" sources override previous ones so there's no need for transforms

You can't just change a setting and move from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core. Check the migration guide at Upgrade from ASP.NET Framework to ASP.NET Core. Some web app types like WebForms were abandoned completely so you'll have to rewrite them with eg Razor Pages or Blazor.

Ok, thanks for your reply Panagiotis, it is an WPF App. How do I switch the configuration there on different build settings, Debug / Release?

The configuration middleware is the same for all application types. The Configuration in .NET docs cover the same concepts for a different audience. There are migration docs for WPF too How to upgrade a WPF desktop app to .NET 8, which covers configuration as well.

As the docs explain you can use the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager compatibility package at first, until you migrate to .NET Configuration.
